# Kyocera FS-2020D printer does not work

Tags: 10.10, printing

I have a Kyocera FS-2020D. I followed the manufacturer instructions to install the printer, but it does not work.

Manufacturer's PPD for the printer: http://usa.kyoceramita.com/americas/jsp/upload/resource/19915/0/Kyocera_FS-2020D.PPD

Cups always says processing and than nothing happens. I use PCL 6 emulation in the printer but tried the KPDL also.

I contacted the Kyocera support, and they provided me a Mac OSX driver and they told me that will work because linux and mac are unix based systems...

I tried to print from command line. I run this command:

```
echo -en "Hello World!" > /dev/usb/lp0
```

But I never got back the prompt. Maybe this is some sort of communication problem related to the kernel? (There is no problem printig from windows)

Thank you in advance all help.

Answer (score 2):

Can you be specific as to what kind of driver they gave you? (Just update your question with the information you have)

I was not able to find a page for your printer in the openprinting database, however there is one for an [FS-2000D](http://www.openprinting.org/printer/Kyocera/Kyocera-FS-2000D), which appears to be a slightly older model.

Can you install [openprinting-ppds](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openprinting-ppds), this should add a bunch of drivers to your install. Can you then update your question if that helps?

Comment: Thank you for your help.

I tried to print from command line. I run this command:
echo -en "Hello World!" > /dev/usb/lp0
But I never got back the prompt. Maybe this is some sort of communication problem related to the kernel? (There is no problem printig from windows)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is relatively simple, but not at all obvious: don't use the PPD ubuntu will offer you, and definitely not the one from the Kyocera website. Select 2000D as Jorge said, then this PPD: “Kyocera FS-2000D - CUPS+Gutenprint v5.2.8-pre1”. The Gutenprint thing does the trick for me.

Comment: This question was from two years ago, and on a release that is no longer supported.  Presumably the OP has long since solved their problem.  It's not clear whether this solution is relevant to current releases, or only 10.10